# Definir um zoom padrão para o google maps

Tags: php, javascript, html

Bom dia,

estou com uma duvida sobre o google maps. Estou com um mapa de localização de uma empresa,porem eu gostaria de colocar um zoom padrao, por exemplo, zoom 3, que ao abrir a pagina, o zoom fique 3 automaticamente.

```
    <iframe width="940" height="368" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"
            marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"
            src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3600.4437971068405!2d-54.5645733!3d-25.52359!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x94f690f5e6033f2f%3A0x3b3245f53467c160!2sZeni+Motors!5e0!3m2!1spt-BR!2sbr!4v1442932960309"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segue script com opções de rolagem de mouse, zoom, entre outras opções:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>
 <script>
                    //Chamar mapa 
                    function initialize() {
                        // Create a map object, and include the MapTypeId to add
                        // to the map type control.
                        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-27.230399, -52.028978);
                        var myOptions = {
                            zoom: 15,
                            center: latlng, //localizacao do ponteiro, definida acima na var latlng.
                            scrollwheel: false, //desativar scroll
                            mapTypeControl: false, //desativa opcao de escolha de mapa
                            panControl: false, //desativa movimentacao no mapa
                            //zoomControl: false, //desativa zomm no mapa
                        };
                        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapa_localiza"), //mapa_localiza é o id o quale usado na div a baixo para chamar o mapa.
                            myOptions);
                        //define o ponteiro 
                        var image = '<?php print base_url(); ?>web-files/site/img/marker.png';
                        var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: latlng,
                            map: map,
                            icon: image
                        });
                    }
                    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
                </script>

                <div id="mapa_contato">
                    <div id="mapa_localiza" style="height: 26em; width: 100%; float: left;"></div><!--CHAMA O MAPA, define altura do mesmo-->
                </div>
```

No campo Zoom, você pode definir o zoom inicial.
Na `var` image você pode definir o cursor do mapa.

Comment: Obrigado, inclui no projeto e funcionou perfeitamente!